# Drag Scale on Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, scale, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to drag the scale on a Leaflet map ?

`L.control.scale({'position':'bottomleft', 'metric':true,'imperial':false}).addTo(map);`

I used this possibility for a wind rose with this code

```
north.onAdd = function(map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create("div", "info legend");
    div.innerHTML = '<img src="/gps/images/compas-120.png">';
    var draggable = new L.Draggable(div);
    draggable.enable()
    return div;
}
north.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , it's actually quite simple. Get the container of the scale control with the `.getContainer()` method and then make it draggable:

```
var controlScale = L.control.scale({'position':'bottomleft', 'metric':true,'imperial':false}).addTo(map);
var scaleContainer = controlScale.getContainer();

var draggable = new L.Draggable(scaleContainer);
draggable.enable();
```

Answer (score 1):

I just applied your solution for the scale "Leaflet.GraphicScale" , it's also valid

```
var graphicScale = L.control.graphicScale({position: 'bottomleft', doubleLine:true, fill:true}).addTo(map);
var scaleText = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'scaleText' );
graphicScale._container.insertBefore(scaleText, graphicScale._container.firstChild);

var scaleContainer = graphicScale.getContainer();
var draggable = new L.Draggable(scaleContainer);
draggable.enable();
```